# View Model Property of particular type allow null in Form Post

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model, modelstate

I have this Model:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public RegisterViewModel RegisterVm { get; set; }

        public Resume Resume { get; set; }

        public Availability Availability { get; set; }

        public PostRequirements PostReq { get; set; }



    }
```

In form post action i am checking if model is valid continue else not, what i want is if **PostReq** is null in that case **ModelState** Validity can be true because in some case it will be null and ifs null i dont want to be checking it for validating.

Currently if it null, ModelState is invalid.

How can i do it?

I know for long, int etc we can make them nullable, but how to do on custom class type?

Comment: if you can put your `Action` code so I can draft.